# why session_id column from customer_visitor table got deprecated in Magento 2.4 latest versions?

Tags: customer, magento2.4, deprecated

In Magento 2.4.5 installed in my local server i noticed that `session_id` column from `customer_visitor` table got deprecated but i can't seem to find any details of documentation for why it got deprecated ?

[image]

Any leads to some docs would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Security highlights in magento release notes of 2.4.3-p1 its deprecated
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/release/notes/security-patches/2-4-3-p1.html?lang=en